# Popup on complete load of HTML page

Tags: javascript

Here it is the situation....
I have designed a demo which is made up of HTML in which there are several images and we have made it such a way that it works offline also for ipad using manifest file.
so so once the project/demo is loaded one can use it off line and book mark it so that he can use it any time he wants.

here is the link for reference:

- http://iwdfvm2730.wdf.sap.corp:1079/speeddemo/dpr921/

I need help from you guys to show a popup/loader icon when the data or every thing is loaded completely.

thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

What you gave us looks like an internal corporate address, but unless you dynamically load resources, I'd suggest that you set up an onload handler: `<body onload="pageLoaded()">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the jQuery .load() function. Excerpt from [the documentation page on the .ready() function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

So, in essence, the .ready() function executes after loading the DOM, while the .load() function executes after all page assets (including script, CSS and image references) have loaded.